# How to remove and update data on relations table using laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

I have three tables. they are,

```
  users
id    name
1    personA
2    personB
3    personC

  skills
id   name
1    html
2    css
3    javascript

   userskills
userid   skills_id
2           3
2           1
1           2
1           3
```

I get the data through the request like `[2,1] and the user id 2`. `On the user skills table in userid 2 there are skills_id`3,1`. Now i have to remove skills_id 3 and insert skills_id 2 on the userid 2.`

How can i achieve it through laravel eloquent method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a pivot table you can use `belongsToMany` relationship. Adding the relationship in your `User` Model

```
public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'userskills','userid', 'skills_id');
        //userskills is the pivot table  
    }
```

Now to update use the `sync` method.

```
$user = User::findOrFail(2); //your request id
$user->skills()->sync([1, 2]); //request array
```

This will remove the 3 from the pivot table and add 2 in the table.

Read more about this relationship in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: It works but it saves the data the data like 1,2 in the same column, but we want to create fields separately like the userskills table. do u have any idea for that @zahid hasan emon

Comment: it should work as you are saying. separate rows for separate ids. can you show me how are you doing this?

Comment: I am doing in the same way you mentioned above

Comment: I found where my mistake is. I converted my request value to integer and it works fine. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little ambiguous but lets assume that you are getting the user id 2 and the skills you want to remove from userskills is 2,1

For deleting

```
UserSkills::where(['userid' => 2 ])->whereIn('skills_id',[2,1])->delete();
```

For inserting

```
UserSkills::create(['skills_id' => 2, 'userid' => 2 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach using relation would be

```
$user->skills()->sync([2, 1]);
```

Sync will remove those skills which are not present in the sync method.